# how to show the value and image in td using ajax after success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

when i refresh the page it show value and image in td  ,but when you click td it will perform an inline edit function after its show the edited value in td the image in td is disappear,i want the image to stable after td is edited ,can anyone take a look at my code and guide me.thanks

below is my code

**Ajax**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('td.edit').click(function () {   

            $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
            $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');

            $(this).addClass('ajax');
            $(this).html('<input id="editbox"  size="10" type="text" value="' + $(this).text() + '">');

            $('#editbox').focus();
        }


    );

    $('td.edit').keydown(function (event) {


            arr = $(this).attr('class').split(" ");


            if (event.which == 13) {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "supplierprice/config.php",
                    data: "value=" + $('.ajax input').val() + "&rowid=" + arr[2] + "&field=" + arr[1],
                    success: function (data) {

                        $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
                        $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');


                    }
                });
            }
        }


    );


    $('#editbox').live('blur', function () {

        $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
        $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');


    });

});
```

**Html:**

```
<table id="sorting" class="tablesorter" style="width: 100px;" >        
<tbody >
<?php

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM supplierprice ");


while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{

if($alt == 1)
        {
           echo '<tr class="alt">';
           $alt = 0;
        }
        else
        {
           echo '<tr>';
           $alt = 1;
        }

echo '  <td class="edit region '.$rows["supp_price_id"].'">'.$rows["region"].'</td>
        <td class="edit country '.$rows["supp_price_id"].'">'.$rows["country"].'</td>
        <td class="edit networkname '.$rows["supp_price_id"].'">'.$rows["networkname"].'</td>
        <td class="edit mcc '.$rows["supp_price_id"].'">'.$rows["mcc"].'</td>    
        <td class="edit mnc '.$rows["supp_price_id"].'">'.$rows["mnc"].'</td>
        <td class="edit mnp '.$rows["supp_price_id"].'">'.$rows["mnp"].'</td>';


$ColumnNames = mysql_query("SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = 'supplierprice' AND column_name NOT
IN ('supp_price_id','region', 'country', 'networkname', 'mcc', 'mnc', 'mnp'
)") or die("mysql error"); 
$columnArray=array();
$i=0;
while($rows1=mysql_fetch_array($ColumnNames))
{

$columnArray[]=$rows1[0];

echo '<td width="0px;" class="edit '.$columnArray[$i].' '.$rows["supp_price_id"].'">'.$rows[$columnArray[$i]].'<div style="margin:0px;"><a class="big-link" data-reveal-id="myModal">
            <span>  <img id="logo"  src="/image/Picture8.png" style="margin:0px;cursor:pointer;"></span>
        </a> <a class="big-link" data-reveal-id="doubleModal">
            <span>  <img id="logo"  src="/image/Picture7.png" style="margin:0px;cursor:pointer;"></span>
        </a> <div> </td>';          


$i++;
}    
echo '</tr>';
    }
    ?>
       </tbody>
       </table>
```

Comment: It would help a LOT if you narrowed down your question to the relevant code, or do more explaining of what you're trying to do and less mass-pasting.

Comment: when i refresh the page it show value and image in td  ,but when you click td it will perform an inline edit function after its show the edited value in td the image in td is disappear when td is edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your td.edit on click function you're setting the HTML of that cell to an input box effectively overwriting the image. The only way to fix it would be to reset the image after you finish editing or put the image in a different cell.